# In ggplot I'm trying to reverse the fill order of a geom_col plot, or put the bottom values on top

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code filters the CASE_STATUS values into Confirmed and Probable cases with Probable on the bottom of the y-axis
I would like to reverse this so Probable is on top because there are a lot less probable cases.

```
geom_col(aes(x = Date, y = Cases, fill = CASE_STATUS))+
```

Comment: Try `geom_col(....., position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))`.

Comment: Super, thank you very much.